# Как сделать анимация набора текста в Label?

Tags: swift, анимация

Как сделать чтобы текст набирался плавно, у меня в начале идет плавный набор, но потом рывками и частями появляется. Подскажите пожалуйста, что поправить в коде:

```
extension UILabel {
    func animate(newText: String, characterDelay: TimeInterval) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.text = ""
            for (index, character) in newText.enumerated() {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + characterDelay * Double(index)) {
                    self.text?.append(character)
                    self.fadeTransition(0.2)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension UIView {
    
    func fadeTransition(_ duration:CFTimeInterval) {
        let animation = CATransition()
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
        animation.type = CATransitionType.fade
        animation.duration = duration
        layer.add(animation, forKey: CATransitionType.fade.rawValue)
    }
}
```

далее во viewDidLoad вызываю метод

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Label.animate(newText: """
Здесь много текста.
""", characterDelay: 0.1)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
extension UILabel {
    func animation(typing value: String, duration: Double){
        for char in value {
            self.text?.append(char)
            RunLoop.current.run(until: Date() + duration)
        }
    }
}
```

И вызывайте во viewDidAppear, а не во viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    Label.text = ""
    Label.animation(typing: "Здесь много всякого разного текста.", duration: 0.1)
}
```

Comment: Супер, все работает. Спасибо большое! Я пытался всунуть в другой поток, но что то никак не получалось. еще на другом форуме советовали попробовать с повторяющимся таймером, но у меня тоже так и не вышло. А можешь объяснить пожалуйста в чем здесь суть? чтобы понять на будущее как это работает. я так понял была проблема в том что слишком грузило приложение тем что последовательно выполнялось появление текста в основном потоке.

Comment: async означало, что работа должна была быть выполнена асинхронно, поэтому текст появлялся рывками.